# AngularJS search input with operators

Tags: javascript, angularjs, operators, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to make a search on my website that makes use of operators (OR and AND). I have an array like this:

```
$scope.data = ['orange', 'apple', 'banana']
```

I have an input field with a model. I want a user to be able to search in this input field with "orange OR banana" and it should return both orange and banana. Basically the same as: http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-3/app/ but this doesn't accept operators.

This seems to be a very trivial question but I can't find an answer to this or an working example...

Comment: That depends on how complex of query you want to support. If it just simple onces like `a or b`, `a and b` that would be easy. But if you want to support `a and b or c and (d or e)` that would be on the whole another level.

Answer (score 0):

In the particular example that you've provided, both "orange OR banana" and "orange AND banana" would return the same result set. Seem like it's really an OR search with multiple tokens that you're after. Tokenize the query and match against the data set (or something more complex).

You could use a custom expression to do the matching you need; something along the lines of `data | filter: findMatch(searchInput)`

And put the function in scope

```
$scope.findMatch = function findMatch(query) {
    return function (item) {
        //TODO: comparison logic, return true|false
    }
}
```

View example on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XChjAYsCv1io8ACLI0Me)

Have a look at [Angular doc](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/filter/filter) for further detail on the filter.

Comment: In your exanple, the findMatch function only have a search input, so how could we do a comparison?

Comment: The `data` variable, which is the source data set, would be defined in scope. The function would also have access to this to make the required comparison.

Comment: The `findMatch` should be a predicate function and will be called against each element in `data`, not the whole array, so how could I know the current element being compared.

Comment: Yes, my mistake - the findMatch function should return the predicate function which gets called against each element. I'll update my answer to reflect this. Have a look at the example - http://plnkr.co/edit/XChjAYsCv1io8ACLI0Me

Comment: I see, good to know that it also can be used this way. Thanks!

Comment: No probs, glad it's helped. Thanks for pointing out the error.